# Turn xml into a string using PHP

Tags: php, xml, oracle

I do query an oracle database for a field that stores xml content using blob data type

I want to generate a string to pass as parameter to a simplexml_load_string function.

I am receiving the resource type:

```
object(OCI-Lob)[111]
  public 'descriptor' => resource(118, oci8 descriptor)
```

And using this code :

```
$query = "SELECT xmlcontent FROM myxmltable";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            oci_execute($stid);

            $xml = '';

            while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) != false) {

                // $xml = simplexml_load_string($row['XML']);
                $xml = $row['xmlcontent'];

            }

            var_dump($xml);
```

How can i transform resource to a string ?

The XML i wanto to turn from object to string is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VehicleValidation xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Validation Id="Validation">
        <Vehicle>
            <Year>2017</Year>
            <Brand>One car brand</Brand>
        </Vehicle>

        <Brand>
            <Info>
                <Data>
                    <Address>
                    One car brand Address
                    </Address>
                <Data>
            </Info>
        </Brand>
    </Validation>
</VehicleValidation>
```

Comment: Can you share your `XML` string and your expected output?

Comment: Just add the XML to the question

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to extract from this XML?

Comment: Are you storing the XML as a  BLOB or an XMLTYPE that is using BLOB under the covers. If you are using a BLOB you should migrate to XMLTYPE store as BINARY XML. Then you can get the serialized (textual) format using the XMLSerialize() operators.

Comment: Using Blob and storing XML will try to migrate to XMLTYPE, thank you

Comment: i will extract all fields from the xml as strings to store into a database each into his own column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OCI-Lob` is a class that provides [various useful methods](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.OCI-Lob.php) for interacting with the represented LOB content.

You can probably pass the result of the [`load`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/oci-lob.load.php) method directly into `simplexml_load_string`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($row['xmlcontent']->load());
```

Make sure to consider memory limitations as mentioned on the manual page:

> As script execution is terminated when the memory_limit is reached, ensure that the LOB does not exceed this limit. In most cases it's recommended to use OCI-Lob::read instead.